# How do I disable the huge clown mouse cursor when using a QHD display?

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, cursor, cinnamon

I recently purchased a large QHD monitor for some screen real estate. Unfortunately, as soon as (I'm assuming) Cinnamon noticed the 2560x1440 resolution, it went and blew my cursor up to an annoyingly gigantic clown cursor against my will.

The gigantic cursor is of the cursor theme "Adwaita". I have changed the mouse theme using Themes -> Other Settings -> Mouse Pointer. The new cursor theme only has effect in certain applications however. When I mouse over Skype and GVim, my custom theme applies just fine.

When I mouse over these applications:

- Chrome
- The desktop
- Any Cinnamon component
- Any Gnome system utility
- All title bars

The cursor is ridiculously uselessly huge.

Why does this occur, and how to I disable it?

---

My cursor theme VS the actual cursor in most applications:

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

I am using Cinnamon 2.2.6, compiled from source on my machine. I'm using one 2560x1440 display in portrait mode (ie 1440x2560) and one 1080p display in landscape mode.

My xorg.conf file: http://pastebin.com/bCuGwCAK

Here are all my "cursor" related gsettings:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep cursor
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor priority 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor priority 0
org.gnome.yelp show-cursor false
org.mate.peripherals-mouse cursor-size 12
org.mate.peripherals-mouse cursor-font ''
org.mate.peripherals-mouse cursor-theme 'mate'
org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink-timeout 10
org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme 'mate'
org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink-time 1200
org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink true
org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 12
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor restore-cursor-position true
org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active true
org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor priority 99
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor restore-cursor-position true
org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active true
org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor priority 99
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor restore-cursor-position true
org.cinnamon.desktop.interface cursor-blink-timeout 10
org.cinnamon.desktop.interface cursor-theme 'mate'
org.cinnamon.desktop.interface cursor-blink-time 1200
org.cinnamon.desktop.interface cursor-blink true
org.cinnamon.desktop.interface cursor-size 12
org.mate.interface cursor-blink-time 1200
org.mate.interface cursor-blink true
```

"pointer" related gsettings:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep pointer
org.mate.peripherals-mouse locate-pointer false
org.gnome.gnome-screenshot include-pointer false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer false
org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer false
org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer false
```

"accessibility" related gsettings:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep accessibility
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard slowkeys-beep-press false
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard mousekeys-accel-time 300
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard bouncekeys-beep-reject false
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard slowkeys-beep-reject false
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard togglekeys-enable false
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard enable false
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard bouncekeys-enable false
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard stickykeys-enable false
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard feature-state-change-beep false
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard slowkeys-beep-accept false
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard bouncekeys-delay 300
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard mousekeys-max-speed 10
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard mousekeys-enable false
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard timeout-enable false
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard slowkeys-delay 300
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard stickykeys-modifier-beep false
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard stickykeys-two-key-off false
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard mousekeys-init-delay 300
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard timeout 200
org.mate.accessibility-keyboard slowkeys-enable false
org.gnome.desktop.interface toolkit-accessibility false
org.cinnamon.desktop.interface toolkit-accessibility false
org.mate.accessibility-startup exec-ats @as []
org.mate.interface accessibility false
```

Comment: *Clown Cursor* sounds rather intolerant. It's not his fault for being that heavy. :( So other application's custom cursors are upscaled? Sounds like some accessibility setting (although I have no idea how or where). Any setting with "pointer" in it? Shouldn't necessarily be "cursor". :)

Comment: @Mario: Added settings for "pointer" and "accessibility" to question

Comment: @Mario: The cursor is Adwaita and upscaled in Chrome, the desktop, all Gnome system windows, Nemo, the terminal etc. The only applications I've found where my cursor theme is applied is in Skype, Libreoffice and KDirStat.

Comment: The thing that really confuses me is the fact that scaling seems to be different. Or is the cursor indeed bigger (e.g. no artifacts from scaling). It's hard to see on the photos above.

Comment: @Mario: Yes, there are no visible artifacts from scaling the cursor. I'm guessing it's vector based and can be scaled to any size.

Comment: As for _why_ it happens, it sounds like the system is assuming you have a normal sized monitor with a very high dot pitch (DPI), which would make the cursor seem tiny.  It sounds like yours is a normal DPI which makes this "fix" unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

run `dconf-editor`, go to `ORG > GNOME > DESKTOP > INTERFACE > CURSOR-SIZE`. I used 10 for my 5k display.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it changes anything, but I've found [the following](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=152480):

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface cursor-size #
```

Where `#` is obviously the desired size in pixels. But I guess you've already tried that, considering `20` is smaller than the default(?).

Also note that your cursor is obviously set to `mate`. It's only set to `Adwaita` for Gnome.

```
org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme 'Adwaita'
org.cinnamon.desktop.interface cursor-theme 'mate'
```

Are you sure you're modifying the correct one?

Comment: I have indeed changed all instances of cursor-theme "Adwaita" to "mate" after asking the question. It did nothing. I've also changed all instances of "cursor-size" to low values, which also had no effect. I have rebooted between all these changes.

Comment: Updated the cursor related settings in my question.